# Launch a file in WinRT using half screen

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store

Im trying to open a file in a Windows Store App , with half the screen but so far i havent got it to work

this is the code im using

```
try
                    {
                        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                        options.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseHalf;
                        var urii = new Uri(file.Path);

                        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(urii, options);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
```

the file.path is

> C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\xxxxxxx\LocalState\Data\chap4_slides.ppt

and i can launch the file if i use

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
```

but it doesnt uses half the screen
am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, but the DesiredRemainingView is explicitly a request not a command. As the remarks in the [DesiredRemainingView docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview.aspx) say: By setting DesiredRemainingView, you aren't guaranteed a specific windowing behavior for the source app.

In your case I suspect you're not getting the desired view because your ppt file is launching in PowerPoint on the desktop.

Comment: yes, i noticed that when i tried to open a .pdf instead and got a diferent result.